# In how much time an account is deleted?

Tags: support

This (all stack exchange including  http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com) website is different from what i had assumed .i asked some inappropriate questions and even unethically voted myself from a duplicate account i apologies my misconduct.

i want to delete some of my questions but these are already answered.
i also want to delete both of my accounts. i have followed the prescribed criteria.
little help will be worth for me.
thanks in advance.
sorry for inappropriate questions(https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82949/steady-state-of-diffusion-current-in-semiconductors).

Answer (score 3):

We would prefer you didn't delete questions that other folks have put time and effort into answering. You can delete *unanswered* questions if you must.

If you want to delete your account (which will *anonymize* everything you've posted, and remove all of your votes and other activity on the site), you can find instructions here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

Note that account deletion is *permanent* - if you change your mind later, you can create a new account, but your old one is gone forever.

Comment: i have followed these instructions but both of my accounts are still active.